# Inserting JSON document into mongo error

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to insert the TWDS1E1.json file into mongodb through the command prompt:

```
db.collections.insert( TWDS1E1.json )
```

But getting the error:

> TWDS1E1.json is not defined.

Mongo is not my thing, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: DO you want to append it to existing collection are create a new one

Comment: You can't  use `.insert` command to insert json files

Comment: @VigneshKalai append, apparently it's expecting binary file!!!?

Comment: @VigneshKalai how would I achieve what I'm trying to do? I want to populate the db and run some tests.

Answer (score 0):

In `command prompt` whose directory path is the path where mongoimport.exe is available type the commands

**For normal JSON**

```
mongoimport  -d test -c docs --file example2.json
```

**For array type JSON**

```
mongoimport --jsonArray -d test -c docs --file example2.json
```

Please see docs for more information

Comment: I only have the 1 file at the moment and want to add the same file multiple time to my collection. How could I achieve this?

Comment: This is  typed in command prompt you can either repeat the same command to append the same JSON to the same directory or use some other command prompt instruction to loop this command which I don't know about

Comment: I wrote a c# program to connect to the DB & Client, This way I was able to manipulate the databade fromc# code quite easilly. Many thanks

Comment: nice one mongo db alone is not a good perform when combined with other technology like python,java,etc  it becomes more flexible and powerfull

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the collection.insert() command to insert a file.
insert() is used to insert actual objects, e.g.

```
db.myCollection.insert({"name":"buzz"});
```

To bulk load a JSON file, use mongoimport